# Spacing in a template-like format

Tags: beamer, spacing, columns

I'm trying to make a beamer presentation on how to solve various linear equations through a 4-step process. Because of the template-like format of how I want the slides to look, I was thinking of originally making a table and then copy-pasting but then I realized that it would be easier to just have a command and then do multi-columns. However, the spacing doesn't work out well.

I need to have 2-3 spaces between each of the right lines because some steps in solving equations might not need much work, if they exist at all.

(Also, I always tend to have a "end frame" problem)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\newcommand{\howto}{
Mul by LCD, Distribute \\
\\
Isolate $x$'s \\
\\
Isolate constants \\
\\
Divide by coefficient
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\begin{center}
    $3-\frac{1}{4}x=\frac{3}{2}$
\end{center}}

\begin{multicols}{2}

$4(3-\frac{1}{4}x)=4(\frac{3}{2})$ \\
$12-x=6$ \\
$12-12-x=6-12$ \\
$-x=-6$ \\
\\
\\
$\frac{-x}{-1}=\frac{-6}{-1}$ \\
$x=6$

\howto

\end{multicols}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably something like the following is closer to what you wanted to achieve. The descriptive texts can be placed individually, so you can easily skip an equation line. I have also aligned all equations with respect to the `=` sign and changed the size of the parentheses.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand{\stepone}{\text{1. Mul by LCD, Distribute}}
\newcommand{\steptwo}{\text{2. Isolate $x$'s}}
\newcommand{\stepthree}{\text{3. Isolate constants}}
\newcommand{\stepfour}{\text{4. Divide by coefficient}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\[3-\frac{1}{4}x=\frac{3}{2}\]}

\[\addtolength{\jot}{0.5em}
\begin{aligned}
4\left(3-\frac{1}{4}x\right)&=4\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)     &&\stepone   \\
             12-x&=6                  &&\steptwo   \\
          12-12-x&=6-12               &&\stepthree \\
               -x&=-6                              \\
    \frac{-x}{-1}&=\frac{-6}{-1}      &&\stepfour  \\
                x&=6
\end{aligned}
\]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```